# Custom option templates (radio, checkbox, etc) for a single product)

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, custom, theme-fallback

I've got a Magento site full of Bundle Products, and I'm now looking to add one single product which pulls a different `view.phtml`, and then a different `radio.phtml`, `checkbox.phtml`, etc. So far I've added the following to the 'Custom Layout Update' section on my new product:

`<reference name="product.info">
     <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>catalog/product/customview.phtml</template>
     </action>
 </reference>`

And it's loading `customview.phtml` instead of `view.phtml`, but this still loads the standard `radio.phtml`, `checkbox.phtml` files. I'm not sure how to direct `options.phtml` to different radio and checkbox files. I did consider creating a different theme with these files, but the problem arises with the mobile version of the site. Normally when viewing on a mobile, `packagename/mobile` loads, and then it falls back to `packagename/default`. So if I create a new theme 'customtheme' and apply it as the 'Custom Design' on the new product, then this product won't have a mobile layout.

Does anyone know how to tell `options.phtml` to find a custom `radio.phtml`, `checkbox.phtml` etc (possibly with a custom `options.phtml` file?) and keep everything within the default theme?

Comment: try this one https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem which I'm posting here in case it can help anyone in the future, but for my solution to make sense I had to edit the question, hopefully this isn't against the site rules.

I created a custom layout (not theme) for my product which requires the custom templates. I then found the four files to edit at `app\code\core\Mage\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option`

Here, you can find the line of code which loads the respective template. I added a simple regex check of the layout name. If the product has the layout 'custom_layout' then it uses a different file.

There may be a better way to do this and I welcome suggestions from more experienced devs, but this seems to be working for me. For each of the four files in the directory, find the line

`$this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml');`

and swap it for:

`if(preg_match('/custom/', Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate())){
    /** Loads Custom Selections **/
    $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/custom/radio.phtml');
} else {
    /** Loads Standard Selections **/
    $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml');
}`